# Scala.js: Problems linking Akka.js and java.time

Tags: akka, scala.js

In my Scala.js cross project, I am trying to use the following two libraries in the js project:

```
"io.github.cquiroz" %%% "scala-java-time" % "2.0.0-M8"
"org.akka-js" %%% "akkajsactor" % "0.2.4.16"
```

Each of this libraries works without the other, however if used together, I get the following linking error as soon as I try to create an ActorSystem with `akka.js`:

```
[error] Referring to non-existent method java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(java.util.Date)java.lang.String
[error]   called from akka.event.Logging$StdOutLogger.timestamp(akka.event.Logging$LogEvent)java.lang.String
[error]   called from akka.event.Logging$StandardOutLogger.timestamp(akka.event.Logging$LogEvent)java.lang.String
[error]   called from akka.event.Logging$StdOutLogger.debug(akka.event.Logging$Debug)scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.event.Logging$StandardOutLogger.debug(akka.event.Logging$Debug)scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.event.Logging$StdOutLogger.print(java.lang.Object)scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.event.Logging$StandardOutLogger.print(java.lang.Object)scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.event.Logging$StandardOutLogger.$$bang(java.lang.Object,akka.actor.ActorRef)scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.event.EventStream.unregisterIfNoMoreSubscribedChannels(akka.actor.ActorRef)scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.event.EventStream.unsubscribe(akka.actor.ActorRef)scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.event.EventStream.publish(java.lang.Object,akka.actor.ActorRef)scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.event.EventStream.publish(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.event.SubchannelClassification.$$anonfun$publish$1(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.event.EventStream.$$anonfun$publish$1(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.event.SubchannelClassification.publish(java.lang.Object)scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.event.EventStream.publish(java.lang.Object)scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.event.BusLogging.notifyError(java.lang.Throwable,java.lang.String)scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.event.LoggingAdapter.error(java.lang.Throwable,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.event.BusLogging.error(java.lang.Throwable,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.$$anonfun$loadExtensions$1(scala.Boolean,java.lang.String)java.lang.Object
[error]   called from akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.loadExtensions$1(java.lang.String,scala.Boolean)scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.loadExtensions()scala.Unit
[error]   called from akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1()akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl
[error]   called from akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.$$undstart$lzycompute()akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl
[error]   called from akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.$$undstart()akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl
[error]   called from akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start()akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl
[error]   called from akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(java.lang.String,akka.actor.setup.ActorSystemSetup)akka.actor.ActorSystem
[error]   called from akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(java.lang.String,scala.Option,scala.Option,scala.Option)akka.actor.ActorSystem
[error]   called from akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(java.lang.String)akka.actor.ActorSystem
[error]   called from JsIOC.$$init$()scala.Unit
[error]   called from TennisTournamentPlanerIOC$.<init>()
[error]   called from JSMain$.main()scala.Unit
[error]   called from scala.scalajs.js.JSApp.$$js$exported$meth$main()java.lang.Object
[error]   called from JSMain$.$$js$exported$meth$main()java.lang.Object
[error]   called from JSMain$.main
[error]   exported to JavaScript with @JSExport
[error] involving instantiated classes:
[error]   akka.event.Logging$StandardOutLogger
[error]   akka.event.EventStream
[error]   akka.event.MarkerLoggingAdapter
[error]   akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl
[error]   akka.actor.ActorSystem$
[error]   JSMain$
```

The problem seems to be that both of those libraries implement  `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, but only the `akka.js` library implements `java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(java.util.Date)`. The linker is probably searching for `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` only in the `"io.github.cquiroz"` library and so doesn't find the apropriate method.

Is there any way to solve this problem without dropping one of the libraries?

Comment: Super hacky but: try reversing the order of your dependencies. If that doesn't work, transform `dependencyClasspath in Compile ~= { cp => ... }` to reverse the order in which the .jars of those dependencies appear.

Comment: @sjrd: Unfortunatly, reversing the order of the dependencies also reverses the problem. Now the Akka.js things might work, but the code called from the `io.github.cquiroz` library (like LocalDateTime) can't be linked anymore

Comment: Well ... then I think you're out of luck, except reporting that to the libraries so that they can reconcile each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the very late answer, yes it used to be an issue but akka.js is now (version `1.2.5.0`) using scala-java-time itself, and the two libraries got a reconciliation.